# iTunesconnect App Preview Error

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload an app preview video to my itunesconnect account, but i'm receiving the following error...

```
"This video has audio that is not two-channel, no-surround stereo"
```

As far as I can tell, there is not specific documentation discussing how to deal with this is issue, so any extra insight on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I had created the video in iMovie and (intentionally) did not include any audio. To resolve the issue, I imported a silent audio track, added it to the timeline, decreased its volume to 0% just to be sure, then I shared the App Preview again. Uploading this file worked just fine. Seems the videos have to have audio included.

Answer (score -1):

I have use this tool making the video https://handbrake.fr/ and uploaded the video in iTune . Work perfectly.